# Filezilla - Could not connect to server

Tags: windows-7

I have tried all the methods to resolve it but it doesn't work. Recommend me the pure solution for it. The Username, Password and host name is also correct i have checked it all. What could be the reason ? I have also tried with two different servers but it still isn't working.
Thanks.

this error display every time :

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.testmywebpage
Status: Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known".
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Resolving address of ftp.testmywebpage
Status: Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known".
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a discussion about this at
https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=8281

Looks like your ftp server name "ftp.testmywebpage" is not being resolved by DNS.

It doen't look like a valid server name to me.